# Laravel unable to retrieve angular POST data

Tags: angularjs, laravel, post, laravel-5, http-post

I am submitting my form data through angular controller. The data then needs to be passed to Laravel Controller and stored in database. But, Laravel does not get the data and the values are NULL

**Form**

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="username">Your Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Your Name" ng-model="user.name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="useremail">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="useremail" name="useremail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="user.email">
    </div>

     <div class="form-group">
         <label for="username">Phone</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userphone" name="userphone" placeholder="Phone" ng-model="user.phone">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userpassword">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword" name="userpassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user.password">
      </div>

       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addUser(user)">Submit</button>
```

**app.js**

```
$http.get('http://api.app.mywebsite.com/users').success(function(data){
    $scope.user = data;
```

});

```
$scope.addUser = function(user){
console.log($scope.user);
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://api.app.mywebsite.com/users',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: $scope.user,
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
}).then(function(result){
    console.log(result);
}, function(error){
    console.log(error);
})
```

}

**routes.php**

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
    Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
});
```

**UserController.php store function**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $user = new User;

    $user->name = $request->input('name');
    $user->email = $request->input('email');
    $user->phone = $request->input('phone');
    $user->password = $request->input('password');
    $user->save();

}
```

Comment: In the `store` function, try `return $user` so it returns something to Angular.

Comment: ok, but this will not save the user...the error in laravel log is  -  Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null

Comment: What is the output of the `console.log($scope.user);` line?

Comment: @Bogdan - Object {name: "myname", email: "myname@gmail.com", phone: "999999999", password: "123455"}

Comment: That looks fine. How about the output of `dump($request->all())` if you place it in `UserController@store`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this out:

```
$inputs = Request::json()->all();
$user->name = $inputs['name'];
```